# Special Characters in json file

Tags: android, json, google-chrome, web-applications, homescreen

So i'm trying out googles add to [home screen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) function and I'm trying to get the title of my web app to display a special character in it but don't know how.

```
{
  "name": "aésmé",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "img/icon.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "density": "4.0"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.php",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

Comment: What character encoding is being used to serve up the manifest file? For that matter, what MIME type is your server set up to report for that file?

Comment: There is no encoding the json file is just a static file. It's called like this <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

Comment: The "name" is what is given to the icon when it is added to the homescreen but since there are special characters it's blank.

Comment: Yes, but when the browser follows the link, it is retrieving the file from the server. The question is, how is the server configured to serve up `.json` files?

Comment: GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1
Host:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: type: application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is a charset issue. Make sure that the encoding with which the file is saved matches the encoding reported by the server when the file is served up. If you're using Apache and you've saved the file in UTF-8 (highly recommended), then add the following to your .htaccess file (or to the server config file, if that's accessible to you):

```
AddType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' .json
```

It wouldn't hurt to also add:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Note that in theory (according to the [`application/json` spec](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)), you *must* use some sort of Unicode encoding for your file (UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE)). Make sure you have saved the file in one of those encodings. Also, the default character set (what the browser uses when no charset is specified) is UTF-8. However, browsers vary quite a bit from this.

Comment: No still same thing. It defaults to the title of the page when special characters are used which is funny because chrome will read special characters in a <title> that are html tags &#233;

Comment: @Darkrum - are you sure that the manifest file is saved in UTF-8?

Comment: Thank you it was because the file for some reason it did not save as utf-8 don't know why all my other files are utf-8 just not that one.

Answer (score 0):

It can be one of two:
1. You are messing up with the utf8 conversion. You either didn't convert, or worse, did it twice tesulting with strange looking characters. 
2. If you need to use special characters consider using base64, although it would render the text unreadable in a text editor.