# Accent marks in manifest json

Tags: json, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I need to write this description in the manifest.json:

```
"description" : "Somos la única empresa agroindustrial del país presente en toda la cadena de valor granaria."
```

The problem is when I deploy the app, in google chrome console the accents marks are broken

```
"description" : "Somos la Ãºnica empresa agroindustrial del paÃ­s presente en toda la cadena de valor granaria."
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Could this be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017020/special-characters-in-json-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to modify your web server config, if you are running **Apache** you can create or update your **.htaccess** and add the following:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
AddType 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' .json
```

You should change the Charset to UTF-8, but in this case it's not a problem of the file encoding.

Comment: That fix it! Thank you!